# What service configuration is used for the azure emulator?

Tags: azure

We're using the new feature in the Azure tools update that allows us to specify multiple configurations. Like [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh369934.aspx), we have a "local" configuration and a "cloud" configuration.

However, since I can't see how to specify the "default" configuration, which one is used for the emulator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the "Properties" page of your cloud project, click on the "development" tab. Then, use the "Service configuration" dropdown to select which config to use for when running in the emulator.