# azure: how to switch between service configurations?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-roles

I have multiple service configurations defined : local, testing, and production.

under properties of the web role, configurations tab, I set the service configuration to one of the options.

However, this does not affect the values that I get using  CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key)
Even when set to local, I get the value for the production configuration.

I assume that setting the active conflagration is done elsewhere, or that it does not apply when running local?

I could not find the answer in the pages below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee405486.aspx

[Azure role configuration management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539204/azure-role-configuration-management)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What service configuration is used for the azure emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039499/what-service-configuration-is-used-for-the-azure-emulator)

Comment: Indeed, the correct answer is on that question.